# Eror 'Information:Groovyc: java.lang.StackOverflowError' on attempt to run unit test

Tags: java, groovy

I am writing unit trest for program modules written on Groovy. I get an error on attempt to run test.
Here are settings of Java and Groovy: http://screencast.com/t/Iygdq9zVn6i0   see screenshot. 
Path from my system is '%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%GROOVY_HOME%\bin;%GRAILS_HOME%\bin;'
Here is screenshot of loaded unit test in IDE.  http://screencast.com/t/NGmJYU8BYgG    I use IntelliJ IDEA.

Here is text of test (i've removed everything to localize problem)

package ua.alfapay.utils;
import org.junit.Test;

public class CommissionUtilsTest {

```
@Test
public void testCalculateCommission() throws Exception {
    //CommissionUtils c = new CommissionUtils();
}
```

}

Text of message after attempt to run test:
'Information:Groovyc: java.lang.StackOverflowError

```
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:56)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:36)
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:44)
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
```

Information:26.03.2015 12:44 - Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 17 sec
Error:Groovyc: Internal groovyc error: code 1'

Comment: Hi Have you found the solution to this issue? I just stumbled on it too.